# MS ACCESS "laccdb" in the wrong location

Tags: ms-access

I have an MS ACCESS Front End on the local machine and the Back End on a cloud server when I open the FE the locking table "laccdb" is opend in the FE machine and not on the cloud server where the back end resides all users have full read write permission on the cloud . What is the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

That's expected behavior. The FE is usually just a regular MS Access database, so opening it will create a local laccdb file in the directory of the FE.